# SSDT SSIS Extension installation failed with VS 2019 Enterprise

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I have been struggling to install SSIS extension on Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Error Details:

```
[0BBC:47D8][2021-10-29T20:18:09]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 11
[5288:4B60][2021-10-29T20:18:12]e000: Error 0xc0000005: Process returned error: 0xc0000005
[5288:4B60][2021-10-29T20:18:12]e000: Error 0xc0000005: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0BBC:47D8][2021-10-29T20:18:12]e000: Error 0xc0000005: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

It seems there are issues with my computer. Below is the screenshot that the tool is not able to repair the .NET Framework. Truly I believe this is a good starting point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install .NET Framework manually from the following URL:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102436

If that does not work, try to run the following tool:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135&wa=wsignin1.0